# Radio button for django inline formset

Tags: django, radio-button, django-forms, inline-formset

What I need is a radio button for each of the form in the below given formset.

```
class AppvideoDemoForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = AppvideoDemo

    def __init__ (self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AppvideoDemoForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['active'] = forms.BooleanField( widget = forms.RadioSelect(choices=((self.prefix, 'Set this as primary'),)))

    def add_prefix(self, field):
        if field == 'active': 
            return field
        else:
            return self.prefix and ('%s-%s' % (self.prefix, field)) or field

AppvideoDemoFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Applications, AppvideoDemo, extra=3,form=AppvideoDemoForm,formset=MandatoryInlineFormSet, can_delete=False)
```

But the radio buttons were found to be unselectable and multi-selectable when i tried my own ways.

Answer (score 0):

for represent radiot buttons, you need to use checkboxfield whith radioselect widgets.

```
choices = (('0', 'LORENZO_LAMAS'), (1, 'EL RENEGADO'))
filters = forms.ChoiceField(required=True,
                            widget=forms.RadioSelect(attrs={'class': ''}),
                            choices=choices)
```

I hope this solve's your problem

Comment: I think you are not clear with my question. I have a inlineformset with form AppVideoDemoForm that has a boolean field 'active'.Need to set any one of the form in the formset as active.